# SQL query to DAX in Power BI

Tags: mysql, sql, powerbi, dax

I have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM [table1]
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT [table2].table1_id, [table4].table4_id, count(*)
  FROM [table2] 
  INNER JOIN [table3]
    ON [table2].table3_id = [table3].table3_id
  INNER JOIN [table4]
    ON [table4].table4_id = [table3].table4_id
  GROUP BY [table2].table1_id) as <table5>
ON [table1].table1_id = <table5>.table1_id
```

I need to do the same thing that does this but translated to DAX in order to use it in Power BI, I'm a little lost with with this. 
**I need to get the count of elements in table4 group by table1.**

Currently i'm using the following measure:

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    SUMMARIZE (
        ( NATURALINNERJOIN ( table2; NATURALINNERJOIN ( table3; table4 ) ) );
        "qty"; COUNT ( table2[table1_id] )
    )
)
```

But I Can't make it work. Any Ideas?

This is my relationship model.
[image]

Thank you very much!!

Comment: It's possible to use DAX as a query language, but are you sure that's what you want to do instead of using the query editor? Are you trying to build a measure or just set up your data pull? Some context would be valuable.

Comment: it would be great if i can use it in a measure, but i tried a few things that didn't work, so if  it is a measure, calculated column or anything else would be nice.

Comment: So what are you trying to do with the resulting table from this query? How are you going to use it in Power BI?

Comment: Sorry, i edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: OK. Makes a bit more sense now, but still difficult to answer when the tables are still abstract. If you have the relationships set up in your model, then I don't think you will have to write any joins in your measure. If you can provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then I can probably help.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information i have some confidenciality restrictions to show my problem so I've been very cautious about what Im showing. I just need to get the count of elements in table4 group by table1 and show it in a bar chart, in the X axis the values and in the Y axis the table1.name  I've been trying to use measures or calculated columns but it seems that no function is working. I edited a little more my model for you to see it.Thanks in any case

Comment: From what you have described you can probably achieve it by simple drag&drop to the power BI canvas as long as you have the data in a power bi model and the tables have relationships defined. So first of all do you have the structure from the pic that you have provided in the power BI dataset?

Comment: You don't need to share any confidential data, just an analogous structure. Change the tables/columns/data to something that conveys the gist of what you're trying to do without using any private information.